# Unable to automate uninstalling a program silently from Program files using C#

Tags: c#, automation, uninstallation, program-files, winium

If I place the same file in another folder location it works fine.

This is the code I am currently using

```
 `Process UninstallCmd = new Process();
  UninstallCmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
  UninstallCmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";           
  UninstallCmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C C:\\Program Files\\Program\\uninst.exe /S";
  UninstallCmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
  UninstallCmd.Start();
```

Comment: `cmd.exe` is not the `FileName`. `uninst.exe` is.

Comment: @mjwills `FileName` is the process that will be started, `uninst.exe` is what the CMD will run

Comment: I understand that @CamiloTerevinto . But that is the wrong way of doing it. There is literally no need for `cmd.exe` to be involved.

Comment: If i change the file location to for example c:\test\program\\uninst.exe /S. It works perfectly. Do you think there is a restriction for the Program files folder?